# Laravel routing based on domains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am redeveloping a core-PHP web app to Laravel 5.8 application with (example) main domain: www.maindomain.com, and few route groups based on url prefix:

```
www.maindomain.com/user
www.maindomain.com/admin
www.maindomain.com/teacher
```

The app also has around 50 addon-domains, in the old app, all of them were pointing to one location (example: public_html/addondomains), and the content that was displayed was determined by the $_SERVER['http_host'].

I want to do the same in Laravel, but i can't set up the route rule for the addon domains. So, it needs to route any url that is not maindomain.com to a controller function. Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route::domain()

Example:

```
//http://www.maindomain.com/test
    Route::domain('www.maindomain.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test')->name('main.test');
    });

//http://example.maindomain.com/test
    Route::domain('{addon}.maindomain.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/test', 'AddonController@test')->name('addon.test');
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Make sure you server is configured to serve these domains from single Laravel installation.